# Exception Details: System.Exception: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have seen many posts about this ASP.NET error, but I am having trouble figuring out how it applies to my code.

The page loads without any errors on my development machine.  I only get the error on my production machine.

```
[Exception: An item with the same key has already been added.]
bli_main.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\bli_main.master.cs:149
System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3064
```

It says that the source of the error is on line 149, which is the line with the closing bracket of my Page_Load function.

This is the full source code for the page that is giving the error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class bli_main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

public static string connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connectionString"];

string sql;

//poll variables
List<string> poll_ids = new List<string>();
List<string> poll_long_descriptions = new List<string>();
List<string> poll_short_descriptions = new List<string>();
List<List<string>> questions = new List<List<string>>();
List<List<int>> questionTypes = new List<List<int>>();
List<List<int>> questionIDs = new List<List<int>>();
List<List<string>> responses = new List<List<string>>();

Dictionary<string, List<string>> d_questions = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
Dictionary<string, List<int>> d_questionTypes = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
Dictionary<string, List<int>> d_questionIDs = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
Dictionary<string, List<string>> d_responses = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection connector = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    MySqlCommand command;
    MySqlDataReader reader;

    TableRow columnsRow = new TableRow();
    Table1.Rows.Add(columnsRow);
    columnsRow.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;

    connector.Open();

    //pull table columns from database
    sql = "SELECT * FROM column_table WHERE column_page_key = @page";
    command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connector);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@page", pageNumber.Value);
    command.CommandTimeout = 30000;
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            TableCell c = new TableCell();
            columnsRow.Cells.Add(c);
            c.BorderWidth = 1;
            c.ID = "column_" + reader["column_id"].ToString();
            if (reader["column_type_key"].ToString().Equals("1"))
                c.Width = 600;
            if (reader["column_type_key"].ToString().Equals("2"))
                c.Width = 250;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        reader.Close();
        connector.Close();
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Close();
        connector.Close();
    }

    //for each column, pull all widgets and load them in, and make an add-widget button
    foreach (TableCell c in columnsRow.Cells)
    {
        string column_id = (c.ID.Split('_'))[1];
        sql = "SELECT * FROM widget_instance_table, widget_instance_content_table "
            + "WHERE widget_instance_column_key=@column AND widget_instance_id=widget_instance_content_widget_instance_key";
        connector.Open();
        command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connector);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", column_id);
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        try
        {
            //for each widget in the column
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Table t = new Table();
                t.BorderWidth = 1;
                c.Controls.Add(t);
                TableCell cc;

                string widgetType = reader["widget_instance_content_type_key"].ToString();

                //if it's an article widget
                if (widgetType.Equals("7")) buildArticleWidget(t, reader["widget_instance_content_content_key"].ToString());

                //if it's a tweet widget
                else if (widgetType.Equals("13")) buildTweetWidget(t);

                //if it's a poll widget
                else if (widgetType.Equals("12")) buildPollWidget(t, reader["widget_instance_id"].ToString());

                //if it's a testimonial widget
                else if (widgetType.Equals("4")) buildTestimonialWidget(t, reader["widget_instance_id"].ToString());

                //if it's a standard content widget
                else if (widgetType.Equals("1")) buildStandardContentWidget(t, reader["widget_instance_id"].ToString());

                //otherwise
                else
                {
                    t = new Table();
                    t.BorderWidth = 1;
                    TableRow r = new TableRow();
                    cc = new TableCell();
                    c.Controls.Add(t);
                    t.Rows.Add(r);
                    r.Cells.Add(cc);
                    cc.Text = "Other widget type goes Here";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            reader.Close();
            connector.Close();
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
            connector.Close();
        }
    }

}


protected void buildTestimonialWidget(Table t, string widget_id)
{
    TableRow r;
    TableCell c;

    t.BorderWidth = 1;
    r = new TableRow();
    c = new TableCell();
    t.Rows.Add(r);
    r.Cells.Add(c);
    c.Text = "Testimonial " + widget_id + " goes here.";

    MySqlConnection dataConn = new MySqlConnection(); ;
    dataConn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    dataConn.Open();

    //get widget configuration info from database
    string sql = "SELECT * from content_table, widget_instance_content_table "
               + "WHERE widget_instance_content_content_key = cont_id "
               + "AND widget_instance_content_widget_instance_key = @widget_id";

    MySqlCommand dataCmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, dataConn);
    dataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@widget_id", widget_id);
    MySqlDataReader dataReader = dataCmd.ExecuteReader();

    string article_title = "";
    string article_content = "";

    try
    {
        if (dataReader.Read())
        {
            article_title = dataReader["cont_desc"].ToString();
            article_content = dataReader["cont_content_1"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataConn.Close();
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataConn.Close();
    }
    r = new TableRow();
    t.Rows.Add(r);

    c = new TableCell();
    r.Cells.Add(c);

    c.Text = article_title;

    r = new TableRow();
    t.Rows.Add(r);

    c = new TableCell();
    r.Cells.Add(c);

    c.Text = article_content;
    c.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(c.Text);
    Regex.Replace(c.Text, "<.*?>", string.Empty);


}

protected void buildStandardContentWidget(Table t, string widget_id)
{
    TableRow r;
    TableCell c;

    t.BorderWidth = 1;
    r = new TableRow();
    c = new TableCell();
    t.Rows.Add(r);
    r.Cells.Add(c);
    c.Text = "Standard Content " + widget_id + " goes here.";

    MySqlConnection dataConn = new MySqlConnection(); ;
    dataConn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    dataConn.Open();

    //get widget configuration info from database
    string sql = "SELECT * from content_table, widget_instance_content_table "
               + "WHERE widget_instance_content_content_key = cont_id "
               + "AND widget_instance_content_widget_instance_key = @widget_id";

    MySqlCommand dataCmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, dataConn);
    dataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@widget_id", widget_id);
    MySqlDataReader dataReader = dataCmd.ExecuteReader();

    string article_title = "";
    string article_content = "";

    try
    {
        if (dataReader.Read())
        {
            article_title = dataReader["cont_desc"].ToString();
            article_content = dataReader["cont_content_1"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataConn.Close();
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataConn.Close();
    }
    r = new TableRow();
    t.Rows.Add(r);

    c = new TableCell();
    r.Cells.Add(c);

    c.Text = article_title;

    r = new TableRow();
    t.Rows.Add(r);

    c = new TableCell();
    r.Cells.Add(c);

    c.Text = article_content;
    c.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(c.Text);
    Regex.Replace(c.Text, "<.*?>", string.Empty);


}

protected void buildPollWidget(Table t, string widget_id)
{

    MySqlConnection dataConn;
    MySqlCommand dataCmd;
    MySqlDataReader dataReader;

    //get the poll key of the poll from the widget instance table
    dataConn = new MySqlConnection();
    dataConn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    dataConn.Open();
    sql = "SELECT widget_instance_content_content_key from widget_instance_content_table where widget_instance_content_widget_instance_key=@widget_id";
    dataCmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, dataConn);
    dataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@widget_id", widget_id);
    dataReader = dataCmd.ExecuteReader();

    string poll;
    try
    {
        dataReader.Read();
        poll = dataReader[0].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataConn.Close();
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataConn.Close();
    }

    //get the long and short descriptions of the poll
    //get the elements of the poll from the element table
    dataConn = new MySqlConnection();
    dataConn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    dataConn.Open();
    sql = "SELECT * FROM poll_table WHERE poll_id=@poll";
    dataCmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, dataConn);
    dataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poll", poll);
    dataReader = dataCmd.ExecuteReader();

    string poll_long_desc;
    string poll_short_desc;
    try
    {
        dataReader.Read();
        poll_long_desc = dataReader["poll_long_desc"].ToString();
        poll_short_desc = dataReader["poll_short_desc"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataConn.Close();
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataConn.Close();
    }

    //get the elements of the poll from the element table
    dataConn = new MySqlConnection(); ;
    dataConn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    dataConn.Open();
    sql = "SELECT * FROM poll_element_table WHERE poll_table_key=@poll";
    dataCmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, dataConn);
    dataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poll", poll);
    dataReader = dataCmd.ExecuteReader();

    List<string> qs = new List<string>();
    List<int> qtypes = new List<int>();
    List<int> qids = new List<int>();
    List<string> ans = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            qs.Add(dataReader["poll_element_question"].ToString());
            qtypes.Add(Int32.Parse(dataReader["poll_element_type_key"].ToString()));
            qids.Add(Int32.Parse(dataReader["poll_element_id"].ToString()));
            ans.Add("");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataConn.Close();
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataConn.Close();
    }

    questions.Add(qs);
    questionTypes.Add(qtypes);
    questionIDs.Add(qids);
    responses.Add(ans);

    d_questions.Add(widget_id, qs);
    d_questionTypes.Add(widget_id, qtypes);
    d_questionIDs.Add(widget_id, qids);
    d_responses.Add(widget_id, ans);

    TableRow r;
    TableCell c;
    Button b;
    //for each poll

    //display poll descriptions
    r = new TableRow();
    r.CssClass = "bodysan";
    t.Rows.Add(r);
    c = new TableCell();
    c.ColumnSpan = 2;
    c.CssClass = "bodysan";
    r.Cells.Add(c);
    c.Text = poll_short_desc;
    r = new TableRow();
    t.Rows.Add(r);
    c = new TableCell();
    c.CssClass = "bodysan";
    c.ColumnSpan = 2;
    r.Cells.Add(c);
    c.Text = poll_long_desc;

    //display the questions and response fields
    for (int j = 0; j < d_questions[widget_id].Count; j++)
    {
        r = new TableRow();
        r.CssClass = "bodysan";
        t.Rows.Add(r);
        c = new TableCell();
        c.CssClass = "bodysan";
        r.Cells.Add(c);
        c = new TableCell();
        c.CssClass = "bodysan";
        r.Cells.Add(c);
        c.Text = d_questions[widget_id][j];
        //c.Text = questions[0][j];
        r = new TableRow();
        r.CssClass = "bodysan";
        t.Rows.Add(r);
        int type = d_questionTypes[widget_id][j];
        c = new TableCell();
        c.CssClass = "bodysan";
        r.Cells.Add(c);
        r.Cells.Add(makeResponseCell(type, Int32.Parse(widget_id), j));
    }

    r = new TableRow();
    r.CssClass = "bodysan";
    t.Rows.Add(r);
    c = new TableCell();
    c.CssClass = "bodysan";
    r.Cells.Add(c);
    b = new Button();
    b.CssClass = "bodysan";
    c.Controls.Add(b);
    b.Text = "Submit Poll";
    b.ID = "submit_" + widget_id + "_poll";
    b.Click += new EventHandler(this.submit);
}



//stores responses in database.
public void submit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool valid = true;

    //get the poll ID.
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    string poll = b.ID.Split('_')[1];
    //for each repsonse in this poll

    for (int i = 0; i < d_responses[poll].Count; i++)
    {
        Table tb = (Table)b.Parent.Parent.Parent;
        TableCell c = tb.Rows[2 * i + 3].Cells[1];
        int type = d_questionTypes[poll][i];
        string text = "";
        if (type == 1)
        {
            //throw new Exception("i=" + i + ", cellControls=" + c.Controls.Count + ", cellText=" + c.Text);
            TextBox t = (TextBox)c.Controls[0];
            text = t.Text;
            t.Text = "";
        }
        if (type == 2)
        {
            RadioButtonList r = (RadioButtonList)c.Controls[0];
            text = r.Text;
            r.ClearSelection();
        }
        if (type == 3)
        {
            RadioButtonList r = (RadioButtonList)c.Controls[0];
            text = r.Text;
            r.ClearSelection();
        }

        int element_id = d_questionIDs[poll][i];
        string response = text;
        //TODO: Update client ID from -1 to real client ID after login is implemented
        int client_id = -1;

        //responses[poll][i] = text;

        MySqlConnection dataConn;
        MySqlCommand dataCmd;

        dataConn = new MySqlConnection();
        dataConn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        dataConn.Open();

        try
        {
            sql = "INSERT INTO poll_response_table "
                + "(poll_response_client_key, poll_response_poll_element_key, poll_response_response) "
                + "VALUES (@client_id, @element_id, @response)";

            dataCmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, dataConn);
            dataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_id", client_id);
            dataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@element_id", element_id);
            dataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@response", response);

            dataCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dataConn.Close();
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            dataConn.Close();
        }

    }
    /*
    Response.Write("<table><tr><td>");
    foreach (string s in responses[poll])
        Response.Write(s + "<br/>");

    foreach (List<string> l in responses)
    {
        Response.Write("----- <br/>");
        foreach(string s in l)
            Response.Write("- " + s + " <br/>");
    }
    Response.Write("</td></tr></table>");
    */
}

protected TableCell makeResponseCell(int type, int poll, int element)
{
    TableCell c = new TableCell();
    RadioButtonList r;
    TextBox t;
    switch (type)
    {
        //freeform textbox
        case 1:
            t = new TextBox();
            c.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
            break;
        //yes/no
        case 2:
            r = new RadioButtonList();
            r.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
            c.Controls.Add(r);
            r.Items.Add("yes");
            r.Items.Add("no");
            break;
        //1-5
        case 3:
            r = new RadioButtonList();
            r.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
            c.Controls.Add(r);
            r.Items.Add("1");
            r.Items.Add("2");
            r.Items.Add("3");
            r.Items.Add("4");
            r.Items.Add("5");
            break;
        //default = textbox
        default:
            c.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
            break;
    }

    c.ID = poll + "_" + element + "_response";

    return c;
}






protected void buildArticleWidget(Table t, string article_id)
{
    TableRow r;
    TableCell c;

    t.BorderWidth = 1;
    r = new TableRow();
    c = new TableCell();
    t.Rows.Add(r);
    r.Cells.Add(c);
    c.Text = "Article " + article_id + " goes here.";

    MySqlConnection dataConn = new MySqlConnection(); ;
    dataConn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    dataConn.Open();

    //get widget configuration info from database
    string sql = "SELECT * from content_table WHERE cont_id=@cont_id";

    MySqlCommand dataCmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, dataConn);
    dataCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cont_id", article_id);
    MySqlDataReader dataReader = dataCmd.ExecuteReader();

    string article_title = "";
    string article_content = "";

    try
    {
        if (dataReader.Read())
        {
            article_title = dataReader["cont_desc"].ToString();
            article_content = dataReader["cont_content_1"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataConn.Close();
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataConn.Close();
    }

    r = new TableRow();
    t.Rows.Add(r);

    c = new TableCell();
    r.Cells.Add(c);

    c.Text = article_title;

    r = new TableRow();
    t.Rows.Add(r);

    c = new TableCell();
    r.Cells.Add(c);

    c.Text = article_content;
    c.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(c.Text);
    Regex.Replace(c.Text, "<.*?>", string.Empty);

}

protected void buildTweetWidget(Table t)
{
    MySqlConnection dataConn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    dataConn.Open();

    //get widget configuration info from database
    string sql = "SELECT * from widget_config WHERE widgcon_id=2";

    MySqlCommand dataCmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, dataConn);
    MySqlDataReader dataReader = dataCmd.ExecuteReader();

    int num_tweets_displayed;
    string account;
    try
    {
        dataReader.Read();
        num_tweets_displayed = (int)(dataReader["widgcon_num_items_displayed"]);
        account = dataReader["widgcon_currently_displayed"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataConn.Close();
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        dataReader.Close();
        dataConn.Close();
    }
    string tweets = ("<br/>");

    foreach (var tweet in GetTweets(account).Take(num_tweets_displayed))
    {
        string s = Regex.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(tweet), @"[a-z]+://[^\s]+",
            x => "<a href='" + x.Value.Replace("'", "&quot;") + "' style='tweet_link'>" + x.Value + "</a>",
            RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        tweets += (s + "<br/><br/>");
    }

    TableRow r = new TableRow();
    TableCell c = new TableCell();
    c.Text = "Tweet Widget";
    t.Rows.Add(r);
    r.Cells.Add(c);

    r = new TableRow();
    c = new TableCell();
    t.Rows.Add(r);
    r.Cells.Add(c);
    c.Text = tweets;

}

// called by buildTweetWidget
public List<string> GetTweets(string account)
{
    var ls = new List<string>();
    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    try
    {
        var d = jss.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(
            new WebClient()
            .DownloadString("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=" + account));

        foreach (var x in d)
            ls.Add((string)x["text"]);
    }
    catch
    {
        ls.Add("Unauthorized.");
    }

    return ls;
}
```

}

I have looked for duplicate variable names, but have not found any.  I apologize if this question has been answered before.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `catch` blocks are useless and counter-productive. Get rid of them and tell us the _actual_ stack trace.

Comment: Oh right.  Will do, one moment.  Thank you.

Comment: also, if you do ever catch and have to rethrow (SLaks is right that these are redundant in this case, though...you might want to read more on what finally does), please just use throw to keep your stack trace intact.

Comment: wow - after removing the try catch block, it showed me my true error, which had to do with adding an item to a dictionary.  That was illuminating.  Thanks!  If you post your comment as an answer, I will select it as the answer to my question.

Comment: actually, it might be best to delete the question in this instance

Answer (score 0):

If yyou check this query, it is probably returning widget_id more than once and it has to be unique because you are adding it to the dictionary.

```
SELECT * FROM widget_instance_table, widget_instance_content_table "
            + "WHERE widget_instance_column_key=@column AND widget_instance_id=widget_instance_content_widget_instance_key
```